# How can I use polyglossia for RTL text?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, bidi

If I load the `bidi` package before `polyglossia`, I get the following error:

```
l.243 \__xpg_at_package_hook:nnn{luabidi}{package/luabidi/after}{%
polyglossia.sty: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                 $
```

If I load `polyglossia` before loading `bidi`, or do not load `bidi` at all, I get the following error:

```
test.aux:11: Package polyglossia Error: right-to-left, but (lua)bidi package
was not loaded!.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
```

There is no mention of this error in the `polyglossia` documentation.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia} % Switch these two lines
\usepackage{bidi}        % to see the other error
\usepackage{libertine}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\begin{hebrew}
    הרצליה ביזנס פארק בניין G קומה 9\\
               רחוב מדינת היהודים 85\\
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no error. Show your log file.

Comment: Never mind, updating XeTeX fixed the issue.